Implementing an IIR filter using DFT
I am very new to signal processing and I am doing some numerical experiments to improve my understanding. At this point, numerical efficiency is not very important for me. I am approaching this from a pedagogical perspective only.
I have a causal filter $H(e^{j\omega})$ specified in the frequency domain (that is, I have access to its discrete time Fourier transform). I have a time series data $\{x[n]\}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$. I want to find the convolution
$$ y[n] = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}h[i] x[n - i] \\ \text{(here $h[n]$ is the time-domain discrete impulse response of the filter)} $$
using a computer, for which I am trying to use DFT. In a computer, I will have to truncate the summation in the convolution to a finite horizon $N$. For this, I am doing the following steps:

Fix a horizon $N \in \mathbb{Z} > 1$ (a positive integer greater than 1)

Sample $H(e^{j\omega})$ at $\omega_k = \frac{2\pi k}{N} $ at $k=0,1,2,\ldots,N-1$ and assemble all of them into a vector $H[k]$, the DFT of $h[n]$ (so that $H[k] = H(e^{j\omega_k})$).

Construct the Fourier matrix $\mathbf{F} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ as $[f_{kn}] = [e^{-j \omega_k n}]$.

Calculate $$X = \mathbf{F} \, \mathbf{x}[n]= \mathbf{F} \ \begin{bmatrix} x[n-N+1] \\ x[n-N+2] \\ \vdots \\ x[n] \end{bmatrix}$$

Calculate $Y = H \cdot X$ (where $\cdot$ indicates element wise multiplication of vectors).

Find $v = \mathbf{F}^{-1} Y$ and then extract the last entry of $v$. To get  $\mathbf{F}^{-1}$ I simply calculate the complex conjugate transpose of $\mathbf{F}$.


Conceptually, I am trying to use that convolution is a product in the Fourier domain.
I run into the following issues, and tried the following fixes:

DFT needs circular convolution. Hence, I zero pad my vectors to twice the size.

Issue of IIR filters. My $h[n]$ may be an IIR filter. So I tried an experiment. I chose $h[n]$ as the inverse DTFT of $a^nu[n]$ where $0 < a < 1$ and $u[n]$ is the unit step. The sampling of $H(e^{j\omega})$ I do to create $H[k]$ does not match with the DFT of the time domain signal! In fact, it was off by an aliasing factor as mentioned in this post here.


What I want to do in the time domain is to truncate the coefficients of $h[n]$ to a horizon $N$ and evaluate the convolution. To achieve this in the Fourier domain, will I have to convolve $H(e^{j \omega})$ first with the Fourier transform of a window and then sample from that?
Any suggestions to improve my understanding and to help me do this task correctly are appreciated!

In our discrete-time domain (which this question is), I would recommend against using "$z$" or "$Z$" as labels for signals or matrices.  "$z$" is the independent variable of the Z Transform.

Thank you for the suggestions, I changed my notations.

Okay, now you have both $\alpha[n]$ and $\alpha(\omega)$.  They're not exactly the same $\alpha$ are they?  Are they related by the DTFT?  Also the use of $\alpha[n]$ appears to be an FIR impulse response.  Normally the letter we use for that is $h[n]$.  But you're already using $H$, so maybe changing that symbol would also be a good idea.  I would change $H$ to $L$ and then change $\alpha[n]$ to $h[n]$ and then change $\alpha(\omega)$ to $H(e^{j \omega})$

If you want me to change the symbols to what is most common and most recognized in the electrical engineering DSP discipline, lemme know and I'll do it.

I made that change and tried to be both self-consistent and consistent with the textbooks and the lit. If you don't like it, change it back. You need to remember that any argument in square brackets, like $x[n]$ or $h[n]$ or $H[k]$ are integers. An argument in parenths can be anything, real or complex.  $H[k]$ is the DFT of $h[n]$ and $H(e^{j \omega})$ is the DTFT of $h[n]$.  You maybe need to review and understand the relationship between DFT and DTFT.

//"To get  $\mathbf{F}^{-1}$ I simply calculate the complex conjugate transpose of $\mathbf{F}$"// - - - - - You also need to divide by $N$.
